# What does joomla 1.7 lack in comparison with drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, joomla, content-management-system

Drupal is considered as more powerful among the two. However, with release of joomla 1.6 some new features have been added like Nested Categories, Granular ACL System, Tableless Core Components etc which were lacking in comparison with drupal previously. So is there any point in using drupal now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion Drupal is better for more complicated sites...Joomla (and Wordpress) can be extended to function as more complex websites but their great strength is that out of the box they can provide the majority of functionality that's needed for a basic website; essentially Joomla is more of an 'off-the-shelf' solution while Drupal is a lot more powerful (it's entire makeup is extensible and modular) but requires more configuration and a slightly steeper learning curve.

Check out [this article](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/blogs/2011/02/02/joomla-1-6-vs-drupal-7-0/), very good comparison of Drupal 7 and Joomla 1.6. The line that sticks out more than any other to me is:

> Drupal 7.0 remains the more powerful framework and indeed extends its lead.

Comment: can you elaborate some of the features/functionality that gives it an edge over joomla?

Comment: I would but it would just be copying and pasting content from the link I posted above; just go to that page it's all layed out pretty well.

Comment: Off the top of my head though: Drupal's core field system, advanced taxonomy functionality, multi-site functionality built right in. There are lots more though, Google is your best friend for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Thats a little bit the issue. I would say that Drupal is inferior to Joomla due to its lack of object orientation, while most of the shortcomings of Joomla can be solved by the huge number of extensions available.

I would say that there is no good answer to this question and the best solution for you will be to test both systems and see which one suits you better.